# Excel: Is there a neater way to do this: dart board scorer returning the check in and check out values

Tags: excel

I'm trying to return the corresponding values from a column, to the relevant person in a row. I have 4 teams of each 2 people playing darts;
(1) for "the check in" (being the first non zero value entered) - all teams will register as highlighted in yellow - M16, P15, U14 & X17 - i want the same number to be returned in their corresponding summary in M3,P3,U3 & X3 respectively.
(2) for the "check out" (being the last non zero value entered when total score (L10, O10, T10 or X10) is zero) as highlighted in orange - P18 - I want the same number to be entered in O5, corresponding to the person who threw it.

I have managed to do this using several formulae in multiple helper cells with Lookup & xLookup and finally IF statements. However I was wondering if there is a neater way to do it

[Picture of data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IewlG.png)

[image]

Comment: So, your question is, "Is there a neater way to do this?"  I think you will see your question closed for lack of focus unless you give it some direction.

Comment: thank you, any advice is welcome being new to this